# How to solve "OSError: telling position disabled by next() call"

Tags: python, error-handling, file-io, iterator

I am creating a file editing system and would like to make a line based tell() function instead of a byte based one. This function would be used inside of a "with loop" with the open(file) call. This function is part of a class that has:

```
self.f = open(self.file, 'a+')
# self.file is a string that has the filename in it
```

The following is the original function
(It also has a char setting if you wanted line and byte return):

```
def tell(self, char=False):
    t, lc = self.f.tell(), 0
    self.f.seek(0)
    for line in self.f:
        if t >= len(line):
            t -= len(line)
            lc += 1
        else:
            break
    if char:
        return lc, t
    return lc
```

The problem I'm having with this is that this returns an OSError and it has to do with how the system is iterating over the file but I don't understand the issue. Thanks to anyone who can help.

Comment: Hard to answer without seeing the rest of your class.  (I couldn't reproduce it on Linux using only functions.)  You might want to read up on [`OSError`'s attributes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#OSError), which can give you (and us) some additional information.  My first question would be, since this is an _OS_ error:  What's your operating system?  Also (possibly related): Why / how are you [opening the file in append mode](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) and then `seek`ing around inside it?

Comment: I'm opening it in append mode because, it is assumed that the file is non-existant before the instance is created. (as you know, I'm sure, 'a' mode creates the file if it doesn't exist yet). I wanted to be able to save space in the code to have a check if the file existed.     My operating system is Mac OS X Yosemite, but I don't think it has to do with Apple.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I have an older version of Python 3, and I'm on Linux instead of a Mac, but I was able to recreate something very close to your error:

```
IOError: telling position disabled by next() call
```

An *IO* error, not an *OS* error, but otherwise the same.  Bizarrely enough, I couldn't cause it using your `open('a+', ...)`, but only when opening the file in read mode: `open('r+', ...)`.

Further muddling things is that the error comes from `_io.TextIOWrapper`, a class that *appears* to be defined in Python's `_pyio.py` file...  I stress "appears", because:

1. The `TextIOWrapper` in that file has attributes like `_telling` that I can't access on the whatever-it-is object calling itself `_io.TextIOWrapper`.
2. The `TextIOWrapper` class in `_pyio.py` doesn't make any distinction between readable, writable, or random-access files.  Either both should work, or both should raise the same `IOError`.

Regardless, the `TextIOWrapper` class as described in the `_pyio.py` file **disables the `tell` method while the iteration is in progress**.  This seems to be what you're running into (comments are mine):

```python3
def __next__(self):
    # Disable the tell method.
    self._telling = False
    line = self.readline()
    if not line:
        # We've reached the end of the file...
        self._snapshot = None
        # ...so restore _telling to whatever it was.
        self._telling = self._seekable
        raise StopIteration
    return line
```

In your `tell` method, you almost always `break` out of the iteration before it reaches the end of the file, leaving `_telling` disabled (`False`):

One other way to reset `_telling` is the `flush` method, but it also failed if called while the iteration was in progress:

```
IOError: can't reconstruct logical file position
```

The way around this, at least on my system, is to **call `seek(0)`** on the `TextIOWrapper`, which restores everything to a known state (and successfully calls `flush` in the bargain):

```python3
def tell(self, char=False):
    t, lc = self.f.tell(), 0
    self.f.seek(0)
    for line in self.f:
        if t >= len(line):
            t -= len(line)
            lc += 1
        else:
            break
    # Reset the file iterator, or later calls to f.tell will
    # raise an IOError or OSError:
    f.seek(0)
    if char:
        return lc, t
    return lc
```

If that's not the solution for your system, it might at least tell you where to start looking.

PS:  You should consider *always* returning both the line number and the character offset.  Functions that can return completely different types are hard to deal with --- it's a lot easier for the caller to just throw away the value her or she doesn't need.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! What seems to be my problem is that i can't call the (built-in) tell() method during a file iteration (line by line). I found a way around this and your answer really helped. Thanks again!

Comment: @BrandonGomes: would you mind sharing your solution with me?

Comment: sorry @marscher I don't have this code anymore. It's from an old computer. I think the answer was to store some meta-data about the file iterator. You could always rewrite the __next__ function.

Comment: To add some color to this answer, the place where this happens in cpython is [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/80b714835d6f5e1cb8fbc486f9575b5eee9f007e/Lib/_pyio.py#L2328). As to why it happens, it's probably because due to caching the actual location isn't 100% accurate. However, it can still be useful e.g. when loading a large jsonl file. In that case, just use `f.buffer.tell()`.

Answer (score 63):

I don't know if this was the original error but you can get the same error if you try to call f.tell() inside of a line-by-line iteration of a file like so:

```
with open(path, "r+") as f:
  for line in f:
    f.tell() #OSError
```

which can be easily substituted by the following:

```
with open(path, mode) as f:
  line = f.readline()
  while line:
    f.tell() #returns the location of the next line
    line = f.readline()
```

Comment: it is not about "inside" but whether that has happened *before* without an intervening absolute seek.

Comment: Great solution, thank you!

Comment: Also if you are on modern-enough version of Python you can write this without double `line = f.readline()` by replacing `while line:` with `while line:= f.readline():`

Answer (score 8):

Just a quick workaround for this issue:

As you are iterating over the file from the beginning anyways, just keep track of where you are with a dedicated variable:

```
file_pos = 0
with open('file.txt', 'rb') as f:
    for line in f:
        # process line
        file_pos += len(line)
```

Now `file_pos` will always be, what `file.tell()` would *tell* you. Note that this only works for ASCII files as tell and seek work with byte positions. Working on a line-basis it's easy though to convert strings from byte to unicode-strings.

Comment: In py3 thanks to 'rb' line is what you'd expect (including line terminators as in `\r\n`) - so this works fine for rewinding to start of line - nifty!

Answer (score 4):

I had the same error: OSError: telling position disabled by next() call, and solved it by adding the 'rb' mode while opening the file.

Answer (score 3):

The error message is pretty clear, but missing one detail: calling `next` on a **text** file object disables the `tell` method. A `for` loop repeatedly calls `next` on `iter(f)`, which happens to be `f` itself for a file. I ran into a similar issue trying to call `tell` inside the loop instead of calling your function twice.

An alternative solution is to iterate over the file without using the built-in file iterator. Instead, you can bake a nearly equally efficient iterator from the arcane two-arg form of the `iter` function:

```
for line in iter(f.readline, ''):
```

Comment: Needed to get file positions at each row in a csv, and the `csv.reader.__next__` method was calling `__next__` on the file object.  This helped me work around this, while still using a `csv.reader`.