# python 3: using file tell() in a for loop yields an error

Tags: file, python-3.x

hi i want to save the position of all the lines that contains "CREATE TABLE" in a list
a) is there a better and right way to do it? (i'm new to python) 
b) why does it matter that tell is being used for the iterator? i thought it's a read method (or equivalent) thus just telling the position shouldn't hurt the file iteration proccess.

so i have the following class:

```
class SQLParser(object):
def __init__(self,filename):
    self.file = open(filename,'r')
    self.createTablePositions=[]
    self.insertIntoPositions=[]

def findCreateTable(self):
    for line in self.file:
        if line.find("CREATE TABLE") is 0:
            print(line)
            self.createTablePositions.append(self.file.tell())



sqlhandler = SQLParser("sql.sql")
sqlhandler.findCreateTable()
print(sqlhandler.createTablePositions)
```

that yields the following error: "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/sqlparser/sqlparser.py", line 18, in 
    sqlhandler.findCreateTable()
  File "C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/sqlparser/sqlparser.py", line 12, in findCreateTable
    curPos = self.file.tell()
OSError: telling position disabled by next() call"

i've searched the net and stackoverflow but i didn't find a direct solution to my problem.
--currently solution like rewritting next() method are beyond my knowledge and i doubt this excercise aims for that.

please your advice will be highly appriciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters, you are never closing the file, that is not good.

The error arises mainly due to the internal behaviour of the `tell()` method. By iterating the file via `for line in file` you are constantly calling the internal operation `next()` which messes up how the `tell()` method works. Usually it is better to use the specific methods for reading data from a file: `readline()` or `readlines()`. Unless you know **exactly** what you are doing, iterating over objects that are controlled by the OS (file system) can cause errors due to conflicting access methods (sometimes) or other.

Also `file.tell()` method returns the position of the cursor not the line where you are. So if say you were reading the first line that had 20 characters, after using `file.readline()` the method `file.tell()` would return `22` (number of characters plus endline character or other)

Rather than what you are doing I'd suggest thinking about it a different way around.

```
class SQLParser(object):
    """
    Parses a SQL file.
    """

    def __init__(self,filename):
        self.createTablePositions= self.findCreateTable(filename)
        self.insertIntoPositions=[]

    def findCreateTable(self, filename):
        temp = []
        with open(filename, 'r') as file:
            # with operator closes the file upon exit of block
            fileNum = 0
            for line in file.readlines():
                if "CREATE TABLE" in line:
                    print(line)
                    temp.append(fileNum)
                fileNum += 1
        return temp


sqlhandler = SQLParser("sql.sql")
print(sqlhandler.createTablePositions)
```

Therefore now, you will parse the file upon initialisation of the class object.

You can then proceed to doing a similar thing for the other method of `insertIntoPosition`.

Comment: hi the thing is i need the amount of charaters to take specific words and rephrase them on another file but that direction is fine i guess.

Comment: hiya thanks first of all, regarding closing the file you're right but i haven't finished the class so it was just a thing i'll do last(btw isn't it like in C++ - the destructor of the object doesn't handle it by itself?). one last question how do i jump let's say to row 16 in the file? if you can answer that (trying to find in the python docs) that would be awsome! (that's why i wanted tell() so i can use seek() later on!)

Comment: for the jumping lines: [linecache](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/linecache.html)

Comment: in python there is no garbage collection like in C++, it is automatic (with some exceptions I'd guess but which do not apply to this case)

Answer (score 0):

If your SQL file is too large, there are two solutions according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29618936/how-to-solve-oserror-telling-position-disabled-by-next-call):

1. Using `file.readline()` instead of `next()`

```
with open(path, mode) as file:
    while True:
        line = file.readline()
        if not line:
            break
        file.tell()
```

2. Using `offset += len(line)` instead of `file.tell()`

```
offset = 0
with open(path, mode) as file:
    for line in file:
        offset += len(line)
```