# Meaning of "OSError: telling position disabled by next() call" error?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file

This is almost the same question as [How to solve "OSError: telling position disabled by next() call"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29618936/how-to-solve-oserror-telling-position-disabled-by-next-call). While the older question has received a few answers with useful workarounds, the meaning of the error is not clear. I wonder if anybody can comment on this.

I am learning Python and loosely following a [tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html). I entered the following interactively on Fedora 23:

```
$ python3
Python 3.4.3 (default, Aug  9 2016, 15:36:17)
[GCC 5.3.1 20160406 (Red Hat 5.3.1-6)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> with open("myfile","r") as file:
...     for l in file:
...         print("Next line: \"{}\"".format(l))
...         print("Current position {:4d}".format(file.tell()))
```

`myfile` contains a few lines of text. The output:

```
Next line: "This is line number 0
"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in <module>
OSError: telling position disabled by next() call
```

Googling for this error yields a whopping 6 results. The same happens with Python 3.6.4 on Cygwin on Windows 10.

**Edit:**

The `tell()` method for text files is [documented as follows](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOBase.tell):

> Return the current stream position as an opaque number. The number
>   does not usually represent a number of bytes in the underlying binary
>   storage.

"Opaque number" seems to indicate that I can't just print it. So, I replaced the second `print()` call with `pos = file.tell()`. Same result.

Comment: The "opaqueness" of `tell()` on a file opened in text mode simply means that the result may not match the number of characters you've received from the file, due to end-of-line conversions and whatever other platform-specific differences there might be between text and binary files.  All it's good for is `seek()`ing back to the same position later.  However, the value is still an ordinary integer, there's nothing keeping you from printing it out if you want.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The message means exactly what it says: because you have called `next()` on the file, the use of `tell()` on that file has been disabled.

It might not look like you've called `next`, but the `for` loop calls it implicitly. A `for` loop:

```
for element in thing:
    do_stuff_with(element)
```

is syntactical sugar for

```
iterator = iter(thing) # the real implementation doesn't use a variable
while True:
    try:
        element = next(iterator) # here's the next() call
    except StopIteration:
        break
    do_stuff_with(element)
```

For a file, `iter(file)` returns the file, and the loop calls `next` on the file.

---

As for why calling `next` disables `tell()`, this is for efficiency. It only happens for text files (specifically `io.TextIOWrapper`), which have to do a [bunch](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.5/Modules/_io/textio.c#L1449) of [extra](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.5/Modules/_io/textio.c#L1533) work to support `tell`; turning off `tell` support lets them skip that work. The original commit message for the [change](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/b9c4c3e455b07b362bd886f7e95aed3be5ab51f6) that made `next` disable `tell` is "Speed up next() by disabling snapshot updating then.", indicating it's for efficiency.

For historical context, [previous Python versions](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.next) used a hidden buffer for `next` that `tell` and other file methods didn't account for, causing `tell` (and other file methods) to produce not-very-meaningful results during iteration over a file. The current IO implementation would be able to support `tell()` during iteration, but `io.TextIOWrapper` prevents such calls anyway. The historical incompatibility between `next` and other methods likely contributed to why it was considered reasonable to disable parts of file functionality during iteration.

---

You didn't ask for workarounds, but for the benefit of people who end up on this page looking for a workaround, I'll mention that

```
for line in iter(file.readline, ''):
    ...
```

will let you iterate over the lines of a text file without disabling `tell`. (You can use `for line in iter(file.readline, b'')` for binary files, but there's not much point, because the `tell` disabling mechanism isn't there for binary files.)

Comment: The OP isn't explicitly calling `next()`...and the rest of your answer sounds mostly like pure speculation to me.

Comment: @martineau: There's no explicit `next` call, but `for` implicitly calls `next`. As for the rest of the answer, it is largely speculative, but the old `next`/other methods incompatibility is documented, and the implementation *is* skipping work when telling is disabled.

Comment: @martineau: The answer should now be much less speculative.

Comment: That's definitely an improvement, but I think you also ought to at least explain to the OP how their `for l in file:` is causing an implicit call to `next()` because that's plainly not obvious and they don't seem to understand how `file`s and iterators work.

Comment: @martineau: Explanation expanded.

Comment: This is heavy on the root-cause and the history of why, but offers no solution. The solution mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42150352/202229) is if you want pushback (or arbitrary `seek/tell`ing) you can't use `for line in f:` to iterate, you must do `line = f.readline()`, `while line`

Comment: @smci: Well, yeah. The questioner already found (and linked) a post with workarounds; they asked specifically for what the error means. I suppose I'll add a bit about a workaround anyway.

Comment: @user2357112 Thank you so much for telling indicating this workaround. It really saved my day.

Comment: Very nice workaround, with very few impact on code structure. Thanks!

Comment: We can't do this for `csv.reader`, the only thing we can do is `next(reader)` or iteration, any suggestions?

Comment: @saeedgnu: `csv.reader` objects don't have a `tell` method. Are you talking about calling `tell` on the underlying file? You can pass `iter(file.readline, '')` to the reader to avoid disabling `tell` on the underlying file.

Comment: No, I needed to pass the file object to `csv.reader`, but still use `fileobj.tell()`, I found a solution myself, I just wrapped the file object to keep track of current position, here: https://github.com/ilius/pyglossary/blob/master/pyglossary/plugins/csv_pyg.py#L58

Comment: @saeedgnu: It looks like passing `iter(file.readline, '')` to `csv.reader` works for your use case. Your wrapper is dangerous - it's got a whole bunch of methods inherited from `io.TextIOWrapper` that your code doesn't interact properly with, including things like `__exit__`, `read`, and `seek`. It doesn't look like your wrapper has a reason to inherit from TextIOWrapper.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed that and inherit from object. Not dangerous anymore!

Passing `iter(fileobj.readline, '')` to `csv.reeder` or calling `readline()` inside `__next__` makes it ~3.3 times slower for me. So why do it?

Comment: BTW my use case is reading from `.csv.gz` for example, while showing a progress bar to user (`.tell()` is for progress  bar)

Comment: The ratio of running time varies from 3 to 3.5.

Comment: If you want to `seek` to the first line after ..., be careful: `pos = -1 ;
for line in iter( file.readline, '' ): ;
    prev = pos ;
    pos = file.tell() ;
    if ...: break ;
topline = line ;
file.seek( prev )  # to the start of topline`

Answer (score 1):

If your text file is too large, there are two solutions according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29618936/how-to-solve-oserror-telling-position-disabled-by-next-call):

1. Using `file.readline()` instead of `next()`

```
with open(path, mode) as file:
    while True:
        line = file.readline()
        if not line:
            break
        file.tell()
```

2. Using `offset += len(line)` instead of `file.tell()`

```
offset = 0
with open(path, mode) as file:
    for line in file:
        offset += len(line)
```